# How to test bandwidth

Tags: bandwidth

I have 2 MB Internet Line. 1 real IP how to check or confirm my line is dedicated or my IP is 103.244.185.188 please help me as soon as possible.

How to confirm or test my Internet Line+IP share or  dedicated

Comment: Please don't ask this question a [third time](http://serverfault.com/questions/706669/dedicated-bandwidth-normal-bandwidth-betwen-4-pc-speed).

Answer (score 1):

I use [iperf](https://iperf.fr/) for testing point-to-point bandwidth.

Comment: dos not open it, my os windows 7. can you confirm how to between share and  dedicated . how to test it.

Comment: I never use Windows so I'm not sure how it would work in your OS.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [www.speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net) to test your bandwidth.

Comment: I already use speed test 2 Mbps full show when download. not showing line status share line dedicated line